# Where would a jaxrs:serviceBean be defined?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

I have a cxf-context.xml file that has the following serviceBean (I'm using spring boot for IoC):

```
<jaxrs:server id="cxfFactory" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref
                bean="defaultService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
```

However, there is no definition of what object this points to in the rest of the .xml file. I can't find where Spring would know what class this is talking about. I actually do know what class it is, but how does the framework know?

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you asking about `defaultService` or about the bean created with `<jaxrs:server`? `defaultService` must be defined in any XML file loaded into your `ApplicationContext`.  `<jaxrs:server` is an abbreviation defined in  the XSD located in the header of your *-context.xml` . CXF maps it to  `JAXRSServerFactoryBean`

Comment: @pedrofb I'm asking about "defaultService". I played around with this and found that the class "DefaultService" (with "Component" annotation) defined in DefaultClass.java is scanned by Spring. So, if I rename "DefaultService" to "Blah" and then change the bean reference to "blah", it all works out. 
Is this just some assumed naming convention that Spring requires? (i.e., if the bean reference is <ref bean="abc"> then it will look for the class "Abc"? Seems like this is so based on how I was able to break it.

Comment: @Bey, please check source code. May be one of classes has spring annotation like Serivice or Component with value "defaultService"

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak yes, in the source code there is a class with the "@Component" annotation named "DefaultService"...I was just confused how Spring knows that "defaultService" refers to this object. I think its just some kind of convention that is baked into the framework...?

Comment: @Bey, If you do not specify name in Component then Spring use class name with lowerCase first symbol.

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak excellent! Thanks so much.